# How to use helm to complete sources which are lines in a buffer?

Tags: helm, completion, search

I have a buffer (not a file) containing data. I would like a function that lets the user select 1 or more lines of this buffer, e.g., by typing a regexp, and that returns the result as a list of selected lines.

The result would be equivalent to a `grep` run within `helm` except that, as a result of validating the selection, I don't want to visit the matching lines but get them in a list.

Comment: Does `M-x` `helm-occur` do what you want?

Comment: `helm-occur` is closer to what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
(defun my--helm-source-init ()
  (helm-candidate-buffer <buffer containing data>))

(defun my--helm-source-select-action (candidate)
  (loop for candidate in (helm-marked-candidates)
        ... I can do whatever I want with the selected lines here...

(defclass my--helm-source (helm-source-in-buffer)
  ((init :initform #'my--helm-source-init)
   (nohighlight :initform t)
   (action :initform (helm-make-actions
                      "Select" #'my--helm-source-select-action))
   (requires-pattern :initform 0)))

(defun my-search-with-helm ()
  (interactive)
  (helm
   :prompt "entry: "
   :sources (helm-make-source "Entries" 'my--helm-source)))
```

Comment: Given that this code isn't runnable as-is, I'm not sure it should be marked as accepted...

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, in comes the regex, out comes the list of
matched lines.

Here's a starter for this:

```
(helm-occur-init-source)
(defvar helm-source-lines (copy-alist helm-source-occur))
(setcdr (assoc 'action helm-source-lines) 'helm-lines-action)

(defun helm-lines-action (x)
  (with-current-buffer "*helm lines*"
    (cdr
     (split-string
      (buffer-substring-no-properties
       (point-min)
       (point-max))
      "\n"
      t))))

(defun helm-lines ()
  "Preconfigured helm for Occur."
  (interactive)
  (let ((bufs (list (buffer-name (current-buffer)))))
    (helm-attrset 'moccur-buffers bufs helm-source-lines)
    (helm-set-local-variable 'helm-multi-occur-buffer-list bufs)
    (helm-set-local-variable
     'helm-multi-occur-buffer-tick
     (cl-loop for b in bufs
        collect (buffer-chars-modified-tick (get-buffer b)))))
  (helm :sources 'helm-source-lines
        :buffer "*helm lines*"
        :truncate-lines t))

(setq test (helm-lines))
```

If you don't want line numbers, you can change a few keys:

```
(setq helm-source-lines
      (assq-delete-all 'filter-one-by-one helm-source-lines))
(setcdr (assoc 'get-line helm-source-lines)
        'buffer-substring)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got inspired by this code from `helm-occur`.

Answer (score 1):

[`helm-swoop`](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop) solves exactly this problem.  You can match strings (order insensitive), regexps, and even strings against distance (try out `C-u M-x helm-swoop` or `C-6 M-x helm-swoop`...)

[image: demo]

Comment: thank you very much, I like it. My question was not clear enough. I wasn't looking for an interactive function. I was looking for a library function that I can call from my own code.